# ¿Cómo arrastrar una imagen almacenada en la PC hacia un PictureBox en C#?

Tags: c#, picturebox, drag-drop

**Esta pregunta es auto respondida**

¿Cómo arrastrar una imagen almacenada en la PC hacia un PictureBox en C#?, es decir dar clic sobre una imagen y sin soltar el clic arrastrar la imagen hacia la superficie de un PictureBox y al soltar el botón del mouse que la imagen quede puesta en el PictureBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver esta problemática debemos hacer lo siguiente:

En el **evento OnLoad** del formulario ponemos este código:

```
pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
```

De esta forma indicamos que sobre el **PictureBox** se pueden arrastrar y soltar imágenes.

Posteriormente en el **evento DragDrop** del **PictureBox** pondríamos el siguiente código:

```
List<string> extensiones = new List<string>() { ".bmp", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".tif", ".tiff", ".ico" };
var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

if (data != null)
{
   var fileNames = data as string[];

   if (fileNames.Length == 1)
   {
      string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileNames[0]).ToLower();

      if (extensiones.Contains(extension))
      {
         rutaImagen = fileNames[0];
         pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(rutaImagen);
      }
   }
}
```

Aquí se declara una lista con las posibles extensiones válidas de ficheros que pueden arrastrarse hacia el **PictureBox**, esto es importante ya que perfectamente se podría arrastrar cualquier fichero que no fuera una imagen por ejemplo un fichero .xls, lo cual sería un formato inválido que el **PictureBox** no puede contener y por tanto ocurriría una excepción. En la **variable data** almacenamos lo que estamos arrastrando y soltando en el **PictureBox**. Si la **variable data** no es **nula**, entonces en la **variable fileNames** almacenamos como un **arreglo de string** lo que estaría almacenado en la **variable data**, aquí es importante convertirlo a un **arreglo de string** ya que **data** es de tipo **object**. Posteriormente preguntamos si el tamaño del **arreglo fileNames** es **1**, ya que podríamos tratar de arrastrar varios ficheros simultáneamente al **PictureBox**, y en este caso específico solo nos interesa que se arrastre un fichero. Posteriormente guardamos la extensión del fichero que estamos arrastrando hacia el **PictureBox** y comprobamos que la extensión esté en la lista de extensiones previamente declarada, si la extensión es válida entonces al soltar la imagen sobre la superficie del **PictureBox** esta quedará dibujada en él. Para poder usar el **método GetExtension** de la **clase Path** debe poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Por último en el **evento DragEnter** del **PictureBox** ponemos lo siguiente:

```
e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
```

Indicando de esta forma que el cursor cambia cuando la imagen arrastrada entre en la superficie del **PictureBox**.